# Mysql Table Join on itself

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm flustered.
I'm trying to join a table on itself to check to make sure files we process make it all the way through our process.  I have a simplified version of whats happening as far as the table in an [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c3470/1/0).

I've also used another fiddle to mock up what i'm looking for as far as a [result](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fa9acb/1/0).

I'm trying to avoid having to generate another table just to be able to make this query work, but if it is flat impossible then I have no problem doing so.  Just trying to keep down on the amount of tables is all.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thank you community!

Comment: Please edit your question and include desired results.

Comment: Put some code into your question to help readers know what you're up to.

Comment: He put both the sql, and what the result should look like in the two SQLFiddles

Comment: @iMakeWebsites - what a lot of poster's don't realize is some people don't want to go offsite. They trust Stack Overflow, and don't trust some site X. Stack Overflow allows both code and images. There's no reason not to utilize the resources. Put another way, why should we subject ourselves to drive-by attacks? Personally, I close them as "not enough information to diagnose".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create derived tables and use left join on derived tables. Code below.

```
select 
F1.File as File, 
F1.Status as StatusIn, 
F2.Status as StatusOut 
from 
(
select t1.file, t1.status
from photo as t1 where t1.status = "Raw Scanned" )F1
left join
(
select t2.file, t2.status
from photo as t2
where t2.status = "Processed" )F2
on F1.file = F2.file;
```

Fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c3470/27)

Comment: Works beautifully on the server, thank you very much.  So the majority of my problem was adding the second 'file' from the table.

Answer (score 1):

This works:

```
   select distinct
       (t1.status), t1.file, t2.status as status_out
   from
       photo as t1
           left join
       photo t2 ON t1.file = t2.file
           and t2.status = 'Processed'
   where
       t1.status = 'Raw Scanned'
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c3470/25/0